# SharePoint & JavaScript - The "Open with Explorer" issue

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, windows-explorer

This is a **JavaScript**/**SharePoint** issue. I have a [similar question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/181152/addbehavior-navigateframe-open-with-explorer-sp2010) in the SharePoint StackExchange community but I haven't got anything over there in months. This particular issue is related to SharePoint 2010.

To the ones not aware, there is standard a functionality in SharePoint that allows users to open Document Libraries with Windows Explorer, which is very handy when you want to upload lots of documents or move file/folders around.

When the user clicks a button called "Open with Explorer", **most of the time**, the folder opens in Windows. Common answers like *"Try restarting WebClient service"* will not work, once users do not have permissions to do almost anything in their work PC's.

After researching the SharePoint JavaScript files I found how this functionality is supposed to work:

After clicking the "Open with Explorer" button, some functions will be called, but here is where the "magic" should happen:

```
function NavigateHttpFolderCore() {
    httpFolderDiv = document.createElement("DIV");    
    ...
    document.body.appendChild(httpFolderDiv);
    httpFolderDiv.onreadystatechange = NavigateHttpFolderCore;     
    httpFolderDiv.addBehavior("#default#httpFolder");

    d = httpFolderDiv.navigateFrame("https://sharepointsite.com/sites/site1/docLib", "_blank");
    if(d == "OK"){
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

From above:

- [addBehavior](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535922(v=vs.85).aspx) - not supported by IE 11, Chrome and Firefox, only IE 10 and older. If using IE 11, the <*meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8"*> will take care of it.
- [#default#httpFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531419(v=vs.85).aspx) - a behaviour(?), apparently not used anymore nowadays (obsolete)
- [navigateFrame](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531397(v=vs.85).aspx) - this either return the string "OK" if successful, meaning that the "Open With Explorer" will indeed **Open in Windows Explorer**, or it returns the string "FAILED" and the "your client does not support opening this list with windows explorer" will popup in my screen.

My main concern is, why sometimes *navigateFrame* return "OK" and other times "FAILED"?

Does anyone know what happens "inside" *navigateFrame* or can I check it? Any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was in IE which blocked navigateFrame() call due to CORS restrictions. I dealt with SharePoint 2013 and provider-hosted add-in: I tried to open WebDAV folder (having the URL containing SharePoint host domain) with JavaScript from a PHAI web application in another domain -- PHAI domain. If you've got this problem in IE (version up to 10 inclusively) and you try to run your JavaScript code in a domain different from SharePoint one, try to add your site to 'Trusted Sites' and set 'Access data sources across domains' to 'Disable' or 'Prompt'.

Excerpt from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535922%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) :

> Behaviors are subject to cross-frame security rules where a document cannot refer to a behavior on another server or another domain. In this case, the addBehavior method returns E_ACCESSDENIED. For more information, see the Security section in the Introduction to DHTML Behaviors article.